# How uncompress tar.lz file

Tags: terminal, tar

I was trying to uncompress a tar.lz file.

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/218230/why-i-cant-unpack-tar-bz2-or-tar-xz-files/218232#218232

```
Joses-MacBook-Air:~ joseluisbz$ ls -al /usr/local/Sources/ddrescue-1.22.tar.lz 
-rw-r--r--@ 1 joseluisbz  wheel  80050 Oct  4 14:43 /usr/local/Sources/ddrescue-1.22.tar.lz
Joses-MacBook-Air:~ joseluisbz$ tar zxvf /usr/local/Sources/ddrescue-1.22.tar.lz -C /usr/local/Sources/
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Joses-MacBook-Air:~ joseluisbz$ xz
xz: Compressed data cannot be written to a terminal
xz: Try `xz --help' for more information.
Joses-MacBook-Air:~ joseluisbz$ xz -dv /usr/local/Sources/ddrescue-1.22.tar.lz
/usr/local/Sources/ddrescue-1.22.tar.lz (1/1)
xz: /usr/local/Sources/ddrescue-1.22.tar.lz: File format not recognized
Joses-MacBook-Air:~ joseluisbz$ tar xjf /usr/local/Sources/ddrescue-1.22.tar.lz -C /usr/local/Sources/
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Joses-MacBook-Air:~ joseluisbz$ tar -xjf /usr/local/Sources/ddrescue-1.22.tar.lz -C /usr/local/Sources/
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Joses-MacBook-Air:~ joseluisbz$ tar -xjf /usr/local/Sources/ddrescue-1.22.tar.lz
tar: Unrecognized archive format
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors.
Joses-MacBook-Air:~ joseluisbz$
```

**What can I do?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.nongnu.org/lzip/lzip.html

```
$ tar zxvf /usr/local/Sources/lzip-1.19.tar.gz -C /usr/local/Sources/
$ cd /usr/local/Sources/lzip-1.19
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Custom/lzip
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

To run **lzip**

```
$ /usr/local/Custom/lzip/bin/lzip
```

http://www.nongnu.org/lzip/lunzip.html

```
$ tar zxvf /usr/local/Sources/lunzip-1.9.tar.gz -C /usr/local/Sources/
$ cd /usr/local/Sources/lunzip-1.9
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Custom/lunzip
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

To run **lunzip**

```
$ /usr/local/Custom/lunzip/bin/lunzip
```

**ENABLE without path**

```
# echo '/usr/local/Custom/lunzip/bin' >> /etc/paths
```

Now I go to uncompress...

```
$ /usr/local/Custom/lunzip/bin/lunzip /usr/local/Sources/ddrescue-1.22.tar.lz
$ tar xvf /usr/local/Sources/ddrescue-1.22.tar -C /usr/local/Sources/
x ddrescue-1.22/AUTHORS
x ddrescue-1.22/COPYING
x ddrescue-1.22/ChangeLog
x ddrescue-1.22/INSTALL
x ddrescue-1.22/Makefile.in
x ddrescue-1.22/NEWS
x ddrescue-1.22/README
x ddrescue-1.22/configure
x ddrescue-1.22/doc/ddrescue.1
x ddrescue-1.22/doc/ddrescuelog.1
x ddrescue-1.22/doc/ddrescue.info
x ddrescue-1.22/doc/ddrescue.texi
x ddrescue-1.22/arg_parser.h
x ddrescue-1.22/block.h
x ddrescue-1.22/loggers.h
x ddrescue-1.22/mapbook.h
x ddrescue-1.22/non_posix.h
x ddrescue-1.22/rational.h
x ddrescue-1.22/rescuebook.h
x ddrescue-1.22/arg_parser.cc
x ddrescue-1.22/block.cc
x ddrescue-1.22/ddrescuelog.cc
x ddrescue-1.22/fillbook.cc
x ddrescue-1.22/genbook.cc
x ddrescue-1.22/io.cc
x ddrescue-1.22/loggers.cc
x ddrescue-1.22/main.cc
x ddrescue-1.22/main_common.cc
x ddrescue-1.22/mapbook.cc
x ddrescue-1.22/mapfile.cc
x ddrescue-1.22/non_posix.cc
x ddrescue-1.22/rational.cc
x ddrescue-1.22/rescuebook.cc
x ddrescue-1.22/testsuite/check.sh
x ddrescue-1.22/testsuite/mapfile1
x ddrescue-1.22/testsuite/mapfile2
x ddrescue-1.22/testsuite/mapfile3
x ddrescue-1.22/testsuite/mapfile4
x ddrescue-1.22/testsuite/mapfile5
x ddrescue-1.22/testsuite/mapfile2i
x ddrescue-1.22/testsuite/mapfile_blank
x ddrescue-1.22/testsuite/test.txt
x ddrescue-1.22/testsuite/test1.txt
x ddrescue-1.22/testsuite/test2.txt
x ddrescue-1.22/testsuite/test3.txt
x ddrescue-1.22/testsuite/test4.txt
x ddrescue-1.22/testsuite/test5.txt
Joses-MacBook-Air:lzip-1.19 joseluisbz$
```

Sorry I prefer install in my custom folder!

Answer (score 23):

There's no need to install new software! At least on MacOS 10.15 `tar` has the option `--lzip` that decompresses `.lz` files. For instance:

```
tar --lzip -tf gmp-6.2.0.tar.lz
```

gives me

```
gmp-6.2.0/
gmp-6.2.0/cxx/
gmp-6.2.0/mini-gmp/
gmp-6.2.0/Makefile.am
gmp-6.2.0/configure
...
```

Comment: Very frustrated, I'm on macOS Mojave and I just get `Option --lzip is not supported`.  Any ideas why?

Comment: @JVC Mojave is [10.14](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Mojave), so I'd guess that Apple added that option only with Catalina ([10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina)). Sorry.

Comment: This totally works in 2023 on macOS Sonoma. The only thing is that `-tf` just outputs the archive's filetree to stdout, and in order to uncompress it to disk the `-xf` option should be used instead: `tar --lzip -xf gmp-6.2.0.tar.lz`.

Comment: @Chepe Questn, I know it's been a long time but please consider marking this as an accepted answer if it's possible. It's much more relevant now.

Answer (score 17):

I use `lzip`, which I compiled from [source code](http://download.savannah.gnu.org/releases/lzip/), however it can also be installed with Homebrew:

```
brew install lzip
```

See also: [Lzip](http://www.nongnu.org/lzip/)

You also need to have Command Line Tools for Xcode installed in either case. Have a look at: [How to Install Command Line Tools in OS X Mavericks & Yosemite (Without Xcode)](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/)

```
$ lzip --help
Lzip - LZMA lossless data compressor.

Usage: lzip [options] [files]

Options:
  -h, --help                     display this help and exit
  -V, --version                  output version information and exit
  -a, --trailing-error           exit with error status if trailing data
  -b, --member-size=<bytes>      set member size limit in bytes
  -c, --stdout                   write to standard output, keep input files
  -d, --decompress               decompress
  -f, --force                    overwrite existing output files
  -F, --recompress               force re-compression of compressed files
  -k, --keep                     keep (don't delete) input files
  -l, --list                     print (un)compressed file sizes
  -m, --match-length=<bytes>     set match length limit in bytes [36]
  -o, --output=<file>            if reading standard input, write to <file>
  -q, --quiet                    suppress all messages
  -s, --dictionary-size=<bytes>  set dictionary size limit in bytes [8 MiB]
  -S, --volume-size=<bytes>      set volume size limit in bytes
  -t, --test                     test compressed file integrity
  -v, --verbose                  be verbose (a 2nd -v gives more)
  -0 .. -9                       set compression level [default 6]
      --fast                     alias for -0
      --best                     alias for -9
If no file names are given, or if a file is '-', lzip compresses or
decompresses from standard input to standard output.
Numbers may be followed by a multiplier: k = kB = 10^3 = 1000,
Ki = KiB = 2^10 = 1024, M = 10^6, Mi = 2^20, G = 10^9, Gi = 2^30, etc...
Dictionary sizes 12 to 29 are interpreted as powers of two, meaning 2^12
to 2^29 bytes.

The bidimensional parameter space of LZMA can't be mapped to a linear
scale optimal for all files. If your files are large, very repetitive,
etc, you may need to use the --dictionary-size and --match-length
options directly to achieve optimal performance.

Exit status: 0 for a normal exit, 1 for environmental problems (file
not found, invalid flags, I/O errors, etc), 2 to indicate a corrupt or
invalid input file, 3 for an internal consistency error (eg, bug) which
caused lzip to panic.

Report bugs to lzip-bug@nongnu.org
Lzip home page: http://www.nongnu.org/lzip/lzip.html
$
```

Comment: This worked for me. It pays to note that you'll need to run lzip with the `-d` (decompress) flag:
`lzip -d filename.lz`

Answer (score 9):

I'm agree with @John Perry no need to install.
Tested on my mac **Mac OS Catalina (10.15.7)**

**To see contents of yourfile.tar.lz file**
`tar --lzip -tf yourfile.tar.lz`

**To extract contents of yourfile.tar.lz**
`tar --lzip -xvf yourfile.tar.lz`

Answer (score -1):

here is the correct answer:
`lzip -dc file.tar.lz | tar -xf -`

Comment: Is `lzip` imcluded with macOS?