# How to extract How uncompress .tar.lrz file?

Tags: macos, mac, mac-mini, archive, tar

I have `.tar.lrz` file in mac which I have to decompress.

I have already checked [How uncompress tar.lz file](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/301016/how-uncompress-tar-lz-file) and the solution there does not work. I think the reason is that is for `tar.lz` and I am dealing with `.tar.lrz`

I am trying decomprees file from https://github.com/lin-tan/CoCoNut-Artifact/releases/tag/training_data_1.0.0

Answer (score 1):

You need the `lrzuntar` command, which is yet-another-compressor (it seems it's basically LZMA) in a package called [`lrzip`](https://github.com/ckolivas/lrzip). You can install it via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh):

```
brew install lrzip
```

Answer (score 0):

For a GUI app which can uncompress tar.lrz, use [Keka](https://www.keka.io/en/). After installing Keka (from the Mac App Store) you can use it from Finder. Select your file, control-click, Open with, and then choose Keka.

Keka is rather slow with the tar.lrz linked in the question. But it does uncompress in the end.

Comment: I am not presenting this as being better (or worse) than the answer from @DarkDust. Just an alternative for those that prefer a GUI.